# Dynamics Ax How to Add Filter to Grid

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a form/grid that contain 2 different datasource

I added StringEdit To form StringEdit's EDT is a field From datasource1

I want to add filter to Datasource2 records according to Stringedit

there is relations between tables

`select datasource1
Join datasource2 where datasource2.ImpExtraCostInv == datasource1.ImpExtraCostInv
&&   datasource2.ImpDocNum   ==  CostParameter.valueStr()";`

qbrType.value(queryValue(datasource1.valuestr())));

Why not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be several things.

Did you establish a **relationship** between datasources in datasource properties?

[image]

You can also do it by code by overwriting `init` or `executeQuery` method (depending on what you need is better `init` method) Did you do it?

You will need a code similar to this to filter the datasource:

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum("datasource2")).addRange(fieldNum(datasource2,ImpExtraCostInv)).value(queryValue(datasource1.ImpExtraCostInv));
```